# How to expand kendo ui treeview first item and its child first item

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I want to expand the kendo ui treeview first item and its first child. I have written the code in the databound like

```
 $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeview").expand("li:first");
 $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeview").expand("li:first").children(".k-group");
```

But is is expanding only first item. Not the first child of the expanded item. How can i do this in kendo ui

Comment: Are you using `loadOnDemand` if so, that is not so easy since when you expand the parent, it starts loading the son and only when the son is loaded is when you can expand it to get grand-children.

Comment: @OnaBai yes i am using loadondemand. How can i do that when using load on demand and when not using load on demand

Comment: Only worked for me when I used "kendoTreeView", with a captial "V" in View.

Answer (score 0):

If you load data on demand (eg. via AJAX call), the problem is that the second node (first child of first child) **does no exist** when following line is executed:

```
$("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").expand("li:fist li:first")
```

To achieve that, you must execute that line just after the first expand() finishes execution.

I see two options:

1. by using kendoTree events
2. by using setTimeout (ugly way)

Ad 1.

```
var yourTreeSelector = "#youTreeId";
var $tree = $(yourTreeSelector);
var treeView = $tree.data("kendoTreeView");

var $firstItem = $tree.find(' > ul > li.k-item:first');

console.log($firstItem);
//make sure selector is ok and first item exists
if($firstItem.length){
   treeView.expand($firstItem); //expand first item
   var secondSelectedFlag = false; //init flag to false

   //handler method
   selectSecond = function(){
      var $fistChildOfFirstItem = $firstItem.find(' > ul > li.k-item:first');
      console.log($fistChildOfFirstItem);
      //make sure expand will execute only when node exists and was not expanded earlier
      if(!secondSelectedFlag && $fistChildOfFirstItem.length){
          secondSelectedFlag = true; 

          treeView.expand($fistChildOfFirstItem);//expand on selected node
          treeView.unbind("dataBound");//unbind method
      }  
   }

   treeView.bind("dataBound", selectSecond);//bind a handler method to dataBound event
}
```

Ad 2. After expanding first node place following code:

```
setTimeout(
    function (){
        var $fistChildOfFirstItem = $firstItem.find(' > ul > li.k-item:first');
        console.log($fistChildOfFirstItem);
        treeView.expand($fistChildOfFirstItem);
    },
    3000 //3 seconds is reasonable amount of time
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").expand("li:first"); // expands first child
$("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").expand("li:first li:first"); // expands first child or the first child
```

Answer (score -1):

declare a global variable

```
var counter = 2;
```

Now in data bound event of tree

```
if(counter > 0) {
$("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").expand('.k-item:first');
$("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").expand('.k-item:first .k-item:first');
counter = counter - 1;
}
```

Comment: It would have better to tell what was the reason for the down vote. Also, this is an old answer.